# Flutter, flutter_sound RecordingPermissionException on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, audio-recording

Using

> flutter_sound: ^8.3.12

I'm having an issue on **iOS only**

> flutter: FS:<--- channelMethodCallHandler : openPlayerCompleted
> flutter: FS:<--- openAudioSession [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)]
> Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'RecordingPermissionException'
> #0      RecorderExampleState.openTheRecorder (package:projectName/Controller/audioRecorder.dart:46:9)

I've also added to info.plist:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow the app to record using your phone's microphone in order to record description for the new parts</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```